# Downcasting instance of base class to derived class

Tags: c++, casting, memory-layout

I am interested if it is safe, to **DOWNCAST** (thanks Mike) an instance of a base class to a derived class under certain conditions. I think a sample is the most easy way to explain:

```
struct BaseA
{
    void foo() const {}     
    double bar_member;
    // no virtuals here
};

struct DerivedA : public BaseA
{
    double bar(double z) {bar_member = z;return bar_member;}
    // DerivedA does not add ANY member variables to BaseA.
    // It also does not introduce ANY virtual functions.
};    

struct BaseB
{
    BaseA baseA;
};

// add extra functionality to B, to do this,
// i also need more functionality on baseA.
struct DerivedB : public BaseB
{
    // is this "safe"? since BaseA and DerivedA
    // should have the same memory layout?!?
    DerivedA& getA() {return *static_cast<DerivedA*>(&baseA);}

    double foo(double z) {return getA().bar(z);} 
};

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    DerivedB b;
    // compiles and prints expected result
    std::cout << b.foo(argc) << std::endl;
}
```

In my case, the classes BaseA and BaseB implement some kind of view concept. However, they also hold all the data members required to add further functionality in the derived classes. I know that I could implement the view to hold only a reference to the class providing the functionality. However, that would comes with some drawbacks:

- I need to rewrite the whole interface for the view classes.
- In my case, the Derived classes possesses an extra template argument (a callback type), which I want to have erased in the view. Hence, the view must not hold a direct reference to the classes providing functionality.

I tested my code, it works, however, I don't really trust the approach. And yes, I know I could achieve some of this with virtuals etc. but it is **really** performance critical...

Any ideas, hints, are welcome

Martin

for the interested people:
i changed my design the following way:

```
struct DerivedB : public BaseB
{
    // encapsule the required extended functionality of BaseA member
    struct OperateOnBaseA
    {
         OperateOnBaseA(BaseA& a);
         double dosomething(double);
    };

    OperateOnBaseA a_extension;

    DerivedB() :a_extension(baseA) {}

    double foo(double z) {return a_extension.dosomething();} 
};
```

Comment: Conventionally that's called "downcasting"; despite the name, base classes are usually envisioned at the top of a hierarchy.

Comment: I guess you could also formulate `DerivedB::foo` as `DerivedA& getA() {return static_cast<DerivedA&>(baseA);}`.

Comment: I'd say that if you want to avoid the performance cost of virtual methods at any price you should have a look at static polymorphism using templates to "implement" polymorphism at compile time (vs. at run-time when using virtual methods).

Comment: One last comment of mine: Although I cannot argue with facts for the moment, downcasting an instance of a base class just because you add neither a member variable nor a virtual method feels wrong. I doubt the standard defines a specific compiler behavior when it comes to such an "illegal" downcasting.

Comment: @Roland Sarrazin I am aware of static Polymorphism. I'm working a lot with CRTP library code. Still i can not see a way to remove the callback template parameter from the View classes. This whole BartonNackman &  CRTP stuff still completely f**** my brain :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to the technical side: It is of course forbidden by the 2011 standard, 5.2.9.11, static cast. Let B  be a base of D:

> If the prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B” points to a B that is actually a subobject of an object of type D, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type D. Otherwise, the result of the cast is undefined.

On the other hand I'd be surprised if somebody could find an implementation which doesn't just do it, because of the obvious implementations of classes, methods and static casts.

Comment: I somehow missed your explanation that you don't want to use references, so my point was moot and I have only the standard quote.

Comment: Thanks for the standard quote :-), i already thought something like that and I will reorganize my class hierarchy to avoid this dirty hack! I accept you answer because it clearly states that it is not generally safe to downcast base to derived.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find your approad clean enough for what you're trying to do. Assuming there's a "data source type" `SourceA` and a "data view type" `ViewB`, I would go more like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class SourceA_base
{
protected:
    T data;
public:
    using value_type = T;
    SourceA_base(T&& a) : data(std::move(a)) { }
    SourceA_base(T const& a) : data() { }
    void foo() const {}
};

template<typename T>
class SourceA : public SourceA_base<T>
{
    using B = SourceA_base<T>;
public:
    using B::B;
    T bar(T z) { return B::data = z; }
};

template<typename U>
class ViewB_base
{
protected:
    U&& source;
public:
    using value_type = typename std::remove_reference<U>::type::value_type;
    ViewB_base(U&& a) : source(std::forward<U>(a)) { }
};

template<typename U>
class ViewB : public ViewB_base<U>
{
    using B = ViewB_base<U>;
    using T = typename B::value_type;
public:
    using B::B;
    T foo(T z) { return B::source.bar(z); }
};

int main ()
{
    using S = SourceA<double>;
    S a{3.14};
    ViewB<S&> b{a};
    std::cout << b.foo(6.28) << std::endl; // compiles and prints expected result
    std::cout << ViewB<S>{S{2}}.foo(4) << std::endl; // still works
}
```

That is, all (source/view) types are templated, views contain references, and there are no downcasts. On your reservations for the use of references:

- Re-writing the whole interface: No need now, thanks to templates.
- Erasing callback types: First, type erasure and performance critical applications are not always good friends. Second, you'd better have the callback erase its own underlying type(s), not the view erase the type of the callback. Each class should do its own job. Or, don't erase types and make them template parameters.

I used rvalue-references so that the whole thing works for temporaries as well, as shown in my second example. Maybe constructors are not always complete/correct here. e.g. for `const` references; I reality would have fully templated constructors (accepting universal references), but to make this cooperate with one-argument implicitly defined copy/move constructors is a bit trickier (needs type traits and `enable_if`) and I only wanted to hightlight the idea here.

You may also consider using tuples to hold data, taking advantage of their empty base optimization.

As for your original question, this downcast is something I would never do; for the technical side, see Peter Schneider's answer.

Comment: "You'd better have the callback erase its own underlying type(s), not the view erase the type of the callback. Each class should do its own job." I found some clean reorganization structure that does more or less follow your approach! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code has undefined behaviour, as stated in the other answers. You can avoid that, if you don't mind some truly horrible code, by destroying the object at `baseA` and creating a `DerivedA` at the same location, so the downcast is valid:

```
#include <new>

struct DerivedB : public BaseB
{
  DerivedB()
  {
    static_assert( sizeof(BaseA) == sizeof(DerivedA), "same size" );
    baseA.~BaseA();
    ::new(&baseA) DerivedA();
  }
  ~DerivedB()
  {
    getA().~DerivedA();
    ::new(&baseA) BaseA();
  }

    DerivedA& getA() {return *static_cast<DerivedA*>(&baseA);}

    double foo(double z) {return getA().bar(z);} 
};
```

The destructor restores an object of the original type, so that when the `BaseB` destructor destroys its `baseA` member it runs the destructor of the correct type on the object.

But I would avoid doing this and redesign your classes to solve it another way.

Comment: This is indeed horrible o.0! However, thanks for the idea! I was not aware that I can choose the allocation address with new(&baseA)! :)

Comment: @MartiNito, it's called placement new. It chooses the _construction_ address, there is no allocation happening (that's the whole point, it constructs an object at an existing address, rather than allocating memory _then_ constructing an object)

Comment: Uh, yeah, I think my phrase was unclear using "allocation". I see that the whole thing would be pointless when allocating something, especially when the objects reside on the stack.